# Why does my IDE say "Unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed" for Spark SQL 2.4.4 dependency?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sbt

I have a Scala project with the below `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4"
```

My IDE says

> Unknown artifact.  Not resolved or indexed

I've tried clearing the cache etc but nothing works. How to get rid of the error?

Screenshot below!

[image]

Comment: Is this an IDE only problem? Or if you use **SBT** directly you get any error?

Comment: Can you execute `sbt update` on the command line? Does this finish with `success`? Could you include a screenshot of the IDE with the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, tried that and yep it finishes with a success message but the depedency still doesn't resolve.  Will add a screenshot, thanks!